# How could you get a set of images for every possible colour (16+million of them) to display one upon running a command?

Tags: typescript, discord.js

So I have a colour command for my bot. The user would send a hexadecimal value for args[0], and the bot currently sends a MessageEmbed with .setColor() being args[0]. This is too small for my liking. I want it to be a full image of that colour. This is the code I have in colour.ts:

```
import { Message, MessageEmbed } from "discord.js";

export const name = "colour";
export const aliases = [ "color" ];
export function execute(message: Message, args: string[]) {
  const embed = new MessageEmbed();
  try {
    embed.setColor(args[0].toUpperCase());
  } catch {
    return message.channel.send("Invalid color!");
  }


  message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

And I would like to remove the embed and instead send a URL to a website with a bunch of images of colours. Anybody know any sites/how I could do this without a site?

Comment: Also please don't change it from typescript, this code is written directly in TypeScript and NOT JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not sure I 100% understand -- are you wanting to create an image that is a solid color?  Like with `canvas`?  I can write that up for you as an answer.

Comment: @LindaPaiste yes, that is what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a solid color image using the [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)

Here's a function which takes your color, along with a width and height, and returns a solid color HTML canvas element.  We make use of [fillRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect) to fill the image with the color.

```
const createColorImage = (hex: string, width: number, height: number): HTMLCanvasElement => {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  if (ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = hex;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
  }
  return canvas;
}
```

```
const element = createColorImage('#FF00FF', 100, 100);
```

I'm not sure what format you need for posting to the discord API, but the canvas has a number of methods including [toBlob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) and [toDataUrl()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) which you can use to convert it.

**Edit:**

I'm not sure if discord accepts a data URL, but try this:

```
const attachColorImage = (message: Message, hex: string, width: number, height: number) => {
  const embed = new MessageEmbed({
    image: {
      url: createColorImage(hex, width, height).toDataURL(),
      width,
      height
    }
  })
  message.channel.send(embed);
}
```